# A matrix eigenvalue question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A, B, C$ are positive definite matrices of size $n$, is it true that $\lambda_j(A(B+C)^2A)\ge \lambda_j(AB^2A)$, $j=1, \dots, n$? $\lambda_j$ means the $j$-th largest eigenvalue.

Comment: May I ask which eigenvalue does it belong to? One of $A,B,C$ or somehow for all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is not a (positive) multiple of $I$, the statement is not true in general. Here is a random counterexample:
$$
A=\pmatrix{2\\ &2\\ &&1},\ B=\pmatrix{1\\ &1\\ &&2},\ C=\pmatrix{0.25&-0.2&-0.1\\-0.2&0.25&-0.1\\-0.1&-0.1&0.41}.
$$
One may verify that the eigenvalues of $C$ are $0.4500,\,0.4589,$ and $0.0011$ when rounded to four decimal places. Hence $C$ is positive definite. The spectra of $A(B+C)^2A$ and $AB^2A=4I$ are respectively $\{3.9736,\,6.3445,\,8.4100\}$ and $\{4,4,4\}$. So, $\lambda_1\left(A(B+C)^2A\right)<\lambda_1(AB^2A)$.

Without $A$ (i.e. if $A$ is a positive multiple of $I$), the statement is true, though. By partial ordering of positive semidefinite matrices, we have $B+C>B$. Hence $\lambda_j(B+C)>\lambda_j(B)$ and in turn
$$\lambda_j\left((B+C)^2\right)=\left(\lambda_j(B+C)\right)^2>\left(\lambda_j(B)\right)^2=\lambda_j(B^2).$$